# If $\mu$ is atomless then $F \circ F^{-1} (t) = t$ for all $t \in (0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, quantile-function

I'm trying to prove this property. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R$ and $F$ its c.d.f. Then $F$ is right-continuous and non-decreasing. Let $F^{-1}$ be the [quantile function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493273/the-quantile-function-f-1-0-1-to-mathbb-r-cup-pm-infty-t-maps) of $\mu$.

> **Theorem:** If $\mu$ is [atomless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures) then $F \circ F^{-1} (t) = t$ for all $t \in (0, 1)$.

---

**My attempt:**  Let $a := F^{-1} (t)$. By construction of quantile function, there is $(x_n)$ such that $F(x_n) \ge t$ and $x_n \searrow a$. By right-continuity of $F$, $F(x_n) \searrow F(a)$ and thus $F(a) \ge t$.

Assume the contrary that $F(a) > t$. Notice that $F$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493339/if-mu-is-atomless-then-its-c-d-f-is-continuous) continuous, so there is $b<a$ such that $F(b) > t$. This contradicts the minimality of $a$. This completes the proof.